Is there a term for this problem/conundrum?
Basically, for now until I find out(hopefully) the actual term, I will call this the Loss Conundrum(LC).
LC basically is trying to figure out if loss of the same percentage of whatever (money/favorite food/valuables) is worse/more injurious when you have little versus many of said thing(s).
For example, say 1 man has 100$ and the other a dollar. Each somehow lose 25% of their cash, who is this more detrimental to? The guy that lost a quarter only had but a dollar, but the guy with 100 bucks lost an equivalent of 100 times that, but the dollar guy has only 75 cents left, and the 100 dollar man has 300 times that.
So, is there a term for this? I doubt I am the 1st to think about this.

english SE? $ \ $

I guess this is SE version of ESL meme. No, I just made a few mistakes. @BCLC

Perhaps https://economics.stackexchange.com/ has the answer.

relative value? Or something

This can be applied to nonmonetary things as well. If bananas are your favorite food, is losing half of them worse if you have 20 vs if you have 10? @JRN

See https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/31893, which is not what you want but is somewhat related.

I believe you're referring to the law of diminished marginal utility. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility#Law_of_diminishing_marginal_utility
